# If a baal keri goes to the Mikvah at night are they still a Tevul Yom?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath

Certain types of tumah, like a baal keri, immerse in a Mikvah and then will be known as a tevul yom, [meaning they are impure until the evening](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0315.htm#5).

What happens if they go to a Mikvah after sundown? Are they:

A) Tahor immediately

B) Tamei until the *following* evening

Comment: He must wait until following evening - see Yoma 6a

Answer (score 2):

The Posuk says ובא חשמש וטהר Only when the sun has set is the Cohen טהור. As per previous comment he would have to wait until the next evening

Comment: This verse can easily be interpreted as being sunrise. In fact the gemara has the same discussion. Can you bring a source that backs up your read?

Comment: The pasuk I linked to says “v’tamei ad ha’arev” - he’s impure until the nighttime. It doesn’t say “u’ba hashemesh”